# Zend MVC - new page is not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-mvc

I'm pretty new to php and Zend in general, so I'll try to be as clear as I can. I have taken over a complete web project written in PHP.

In the main layout is script `partials/menu.phtml`, where is a list of few pages. And I wanted to add another one (called pricelist). I created a new `pricelist.phtml` file in directory `info/` with other pages leading from this menu (in *view*).

Then in `InfoController` I created  new `public function pricelistAction()` which includes

```
$this->view->headTitle()->append('Info'); 
$this->view->headTitle()->append('Pricelist');
```

Nothing is written in *model*. When I run localhost and click Info - Pricelist, the page is not found. I have no clue what I might have forgotten or what is wrong. I'm stuck on this for several days and starting to be desperate. I really appreciate any help. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are new to PHP, then why are you using a framework?

Comment: I had no choice, the complete project is running and I am adding new sites and features. Believe me, I'd rather code in something else than php. But I don't have time to write it from scratch again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Make sure there is a proper route in your module.config file that causes this action to be triggered. `/baseroute/:action`  or `/baseroute/pricelist`...something like that
2. There are several ways of loading `views/templates`: Some developers require you to set new view files up explicitly in the `view_manage=>template_map` section of your `module.config` file, rather than let zend handle it automatically.

It's hard to guess without seeing your code/directory structure but this is where I would start.

Comment: You just saved my life, sir. I was missing route in config file. Thank you very much!

Comment: Go ahead and flag it as accepted :), it will remove it from the un-answered queue and others won't waste their time on it!